# Error when compiling Java source file

Tags: java

I'm a beginner in Java and I created this class:

```
class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

as test.java, and when I compiled it with this cmd:

```
javac C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test.java
```

and then:

```
java C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test.class
```

I received this error :

> Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test.class

Comment: `java -cp . test` or use an IDE ;)

Comment: This as nothing to see with classpath...this is just because he added the ".class" extension

Comment: @PeterLawrey I tried the java -cp C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test but it doesn't worked

Comment: Sorry `java -cp C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop test` It's much simpler when you run from the directory where you code is. ;)

Comment: First go to the directory which have your main class using "cd" command.Like if your current directory is C:\ use `cd Users\Aimad\Desktop` and after that just use `java test` thats it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with what you have written is that you have added ".class". By writing this you have instructed Java.exe to look for a class file called "class" in a directory called "test" underneath the one you are currently in. To make you code work remove the ".class" extension and you need to navigate to the file in the command line first. Additionally, the class that holds your main method must be declared as "public".

**Code**

```
public class test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

**Command Line**

```
cd C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop
java test
```

Comment: To expand on Chris' answer, it is usual for "real" Java applications to arrange the classes into *packages*.  For example `java.util.HashMap` is the fully-qualified name of a class called `HashMap` in the package `java.util`.  When you invoke Java, you're not giving a *filename* but a *classname*, it already knows to add `.class` on the end of whatever you ask for.

Comment: The `java` command expects a **class name**, not a path or file name. What you write under "Command Line" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Try ths::

```
java C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test
```

Comment: I tried this but I got this error :

Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test

Comment: This answer is wrong.  `java` expects a fully qualified class name, not a path name.

Answer (score 1):

The solution is either:

```
% cd C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop
% java test
```

or

```
% java -cp C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop test
```

---

Explanation:

1. The argument to the `java` command must be the fully qualified name of the class.  In your case, since your class is declared in the "default" package, the FQN is "test".
2. The `java` command needs to be able the class (i.e. the "test.class" file) via its classpath.  The default java classpath is `.` so the first solution is to change to the directory containing the "test.class" file and so that it can be accessed as ".\test.class".  The second solution uses the `-cp` argument to specify a non-default classpath.

Note that using a pathname to identify the class won't work, either with the ".class" suffix, or with the ".class" suffix removed ... (except as above)

Answer (score 0):

$cd C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop
$java -cp . test

and make class as public

while running the program no need to specify .class and the path it should be fully qualified class name :)

Comment: I tried this but I got this error : Could not find or load main class C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test

Comment: please make change directory to that position and try.? use cd command........ 1.st cd C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop and then Java test

Comment: This answer is wrong.  `java` expects a fully qualified class name, not a path name.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the directory where you .class file is and type the command to run your program.

Answer (score 0):

For `execution`, You need not to write `java C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test.class`
.**class** files is for machine readable so we need not to call them.

simply add the `public class` `name` only such as `java C:\Users\Aimad\Desktop\test`

read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/javac.html)